# Real Analysis Sequence limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Consider the following sequence:

$$
\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} \cdots
$$

a) Prove by induction that all terms of the sequence are bounded above by two.

b) Show that this sequence converges.

c) Calculate it's limit.

---

I'm having trouble with (c). How can I do it using the definition of a limit of a sequence?

Here are my answers for (a) and (b):

(a)

The sequence can be defined as:
$$
x_1 = \sqrt{2}\\
x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+x_n}
$$
Now let's prove by induction. The base case, where $n=1$, we have immediately that $\sqrt{2}<2$.
Let's then suppose that $x_n < 2$. Then we have:

$$
x_n + 2 < 2 + 2 = 4\\
x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+x_n} =\sqrt{x_n+2} < \sqrt{4} = 2
$$

(b) Since $ x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + x_n} $ we can see that $x_{n+1}>x_n$ therefore that's a monotonic sequence. In (a) we showed that it is bounded above, and because $x_{n+1}>x_n$ we can say that $|x_n| < 2$, hence the sequence is bounded above and below. By Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence converges.

(c) From definition of limit of a sequence:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \forall n > n_0 \rightarrow |x_n - L| < \epsilon 
$$

Now I need to find L... How can I apply that definition to find the limit?

Comment: @dxiv It's different... I'm asking about the limit, not the convergence... I've showed it.

Comment: @BrunoReis I know you showed the convergence, in fact yours is a very well asked question and I +1'd it for that. But if you read the answers under the linked post you'll find the respective limit derived in a number of different ways there. For that reason, I am maintaining my close-as-duplicate vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last point you *should not* use the $\epsilon$–$\delta$ definition. You know that the limit exists. Let it be $L$. Then
$$
\sqrt{2+L}=L
$$
or $2+L=L^2$, $L^2-L-2=0$, $(L-2)(L+1)=0$. But $L>0$, so $L=2$.

Comment: Why can you assume that $\sqrt{2+L} = L$ just by knowing that the limit exist?

Comment: @BrunoReis Beacause $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$, and $x_n$ (and all its subsequences) tends to $L$.

Comment: $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ for $f$ continuous. If $x_n\to L$, then $f(x_n) \to L$ and, of course, $x_{n+1} \to L$.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Ohhh that's right. If a sequence converges to L all of it's subsequence converges to L too.. Thank you :)